# winforms webbrowser control access label

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dom, browser

I have a question about the webbrowser control that I hope someone can answer.  I am working on a document retrieval and storing class that uses HTML to display and save data.  I want to use the webbrowser control in winforms using VB.Net.  I only want to store the fields values in the html document, not the whole document.  I am hoping to use labels in html and read them with the DOM of the web browser control but am not sure how to do this.

Has anyone done this before and could someone please provide some sample code on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
 If (pDisp Is WebBrowser1.object) Then
  Label1.Caption = WebBrowser1.Document.All("myElem").innerHTML
 End If
End Sub
```